# How do I consistently interpret PineScript series indexing?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, time-series, pine-script

I am trying to analyse the code by jdehorty posted here: https://www.tradingview.com/script/ia5ozyMF-MLExtensions/

The issue I am facing very often is that I do not understand how PineScript interprets the indexing of its series type. For example, the way I understand it currenty, from reading the documentation of the `[]` operator and watching some videos is that for a series `src` the following is true:

`src[0]` accesses the last value in the series or the latest bar, i.e. the stock value for the current day.
`src[1]` accesses the value of the series one bar before the latest, i.e. the stock value of yesterday.
`src` alone is apparently equivalent to `src[0]`. This I got from ChatGPT in a last ditch effort so it might be false.

This makes the following code confusing for me for the following reasons:

1. `normalizeDeriv` returns a `<series float>`, however, `deriv` is declared as `<float>` within the function and `nDeriv` is just `deriv` divided by another float (ostensibly). How come?
2. Assuming `src - src[2]` is equal to `src[0] - src[2]` then `deriv` should contain like 4-5 values,
   basically the differences of open, close, high, and low between the last day and two days ago. It then makes little sense for it to be a  `<float series>` since it only captures the difference between two days. Would it not make sense to have it as an array of 4-5 values?
3. Assuming `src - src[2]` means the whole time series `src - <the whole time series src but shifted by two ahead>`. Then `nDeriv` would be a time series of the differences between every day and the day two days ago from that day. But then we have ambiguity in the term `src[2]`, does it mean the series shifted ahead by 2 or does it mean the value of the series at the the bar two bars behind the current one?

I am still new to PineScript and have really been looking around but I can't seem to find a definitive aswer, since I am more familiar with Python I tend to think in arrays.

```
// @function Returns the smoothed hyperbolic tangent of the input series.
// @param src <series float> The input series (i.e., the first-order derivative for price).
// @param quadraticMeanLength <int>  The length of the quadratic mean (RMS).
// @returns nDeriv <series float> The normalized derivative of the input series.
export normalizeDeriv(series float src, int quadraticMeanLength) =>
    // Calculate the derivative of the input series.
    float deriv = src - src[2]
    // Calculate the quadratic mean of the derivative.
    quadraticMean = math.sqrt(nz(math.sum(math.pow(deriv, 2), quadraticMeanLength) / quadraticMeanLength))
    // Return the normalized derivative.
    nDeriv = deriv / quadraticMean
    nDeriv
```

I want to translate the code into pyhon using the pandas library. I am unsure if need the explicit values (as in the current code below) or a whole set of them. Something like:

```
deriv = src - src.shift(2)
```

The latter makes more sense here as the function is pretty clear. But I could still be wrong and similarly confusing sytax comes up rather often in PineScript so I wanted to ask.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

def normalize_derivative(src, quadratic_mean_length):
    # Calculate the derivative of the input series.
    deriv = src.iloc[-1] - src.iloc[-3]
    print(deriv)
    
    # Calculate the quadratic mean of the derivative.
    quadratic_mean = np.sqrt(np.nan_to_num(np.mean(np.square(deriv[-quadratic_mean_length:])))) #the last -RMS length elements
    print(quadratic_mean)
    
    # Return the normalized derivative.
    n_deriv = deriv / quadratic_mean
    return n_deriv
```